# Chartjs + DataLabelPlugin: Suddenly data labels are shown in every chart even without the plugin?

Tags: angular, chart.js

My Angular 8 app uses a couple of charts, that I created using `Cartjs` (using `ng2-charts`).

For one chart I need to show the data lables for each data point. So I added `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` to the project, imported the plugin

`import * as DataLabelPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels'`

added it to the list of plugins for the chart

`chartPlugins = [DataLabelPlugin]`

and configured it accordingly:

```js
plugins: {
  datalabels: {
    align: "top"
  }
}
```

So far so good. Everything works as expected. Except, all my other charts now show data labels as well. None of them imported `'chartjs-plugin-datalabels'` or referenced `DataLabelPlugin` in the list of plugins.

The only way to get rid of the labels is to disable them explicitly:

```js
plugins: {
  datalabels: {
    display: false
  }
}
```

But why is this necessary or even possible, when the chart is not even referencing the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of DataLabelPlugin it is written :

> This plugin registers itself globally, meaning that once imported, all
> charts will display labels. In case you want it enabled only for a few
> charts, you first need to unregister it globally

ref : https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#integration